# can't create file which was previously quarantined by free Avira

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions, anti-virus, avira

I wanted to download the game "steep" with steam and got a false positive virus alert by avira on the file "shadercontainer_engine_win64_f.dll". avira quarantined it - so I set exclusion rules for the file and tried again. for some reason steam could not create a file with the same name.
I tried for myself - I couldn't create the file as well. I deleted the folder which was containing the download. restarted the download - same problem.

so somehow avira seems to be able to block a file or a filename which doesn't even exist. it seems to block them for future uses - even if you excluded them in the scan- and search-rules.

any ideas how i could get rid of this weird file(-name) blocking issue with avira?

I am on a windows 10 PC, btw.

Comment: Disable anti-virus, download and install, re-activate anti-virus.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths like i said - i can't even create a file with the same name on my own anymore. and of course i tried disabling avira.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the PC, and Avira will forget this file.

Comment: Can you explain your answer in more detail?

Comment: I had a same problem: Avira deleted my .php file as infected. I tryed to create new php file with the same name, but unsuccessfully. This worked only after PC restart.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue. Tried much but what I think is that Avira permits it being in Steam downloaded folder and that is litterarly it. Meaning steam can't move it to it's destined folder, and gives out a crash (I tried removing it so steam would just have to re-download it, and it wouldn't let me do that). Just remove that ****, stay safe on the web and stick with Windows own antivirus, I tried this a bit because I wanted one for my droid and they had one. But to be honest, I feel it's just a pain in the neck!

Comment: please don't use vulgar language